# Why navigator.credentials.get function not working in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, webauthn, yubico

Calling function **navigator.credentials.get({ publicKey })** from background in Firefox addon throws following error `The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`.

I cant find any information about that issue. Is there any way to use WebAuthn functions in Firefox addon scripts? In Chrome extension it works without any problems.

Comment: I got an answer - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1650441

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with getting webauthn to work for literally months, turns out there's a stupid firefox bug which throws a false negative- If you have the console open, it doesn't work.  Closing the console finally fixed it for me.  Here's the bug report:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1479500

hope this helps,
Kevin